# Disable cache for particular custom block called in layout xml

Tags: magento2, layout, blocks, full-page-cache, block-cache

I want to disable cache only for particular block which is called in some pages like Home Page, Category Listing page , Product page and Shopping cart page etc.

```
<block class="Namespace\Module\Block\Custom" name="custom.storetime" template="Namespace_Module::storetime.phtml"/>
```

and I do not want to use **cacheable=false** as its disable the cache for entire page.

Comment: It's hard to say, but you can use Ajax or private content: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/cache/page-caching/private-content.html

Answer (score 2):

I have solved my problem using ajax post request on phtml file

So I have created two phtml  files and in my first phtml file which show the output data on page reload I have called the ajax post request to my custom controller

```
<div id="customdata"></div>
<?php
$ajaxurl = $block->getAjaxUrl();
?>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
            "*": {
                "Mymodule_Custom/js/custom": {
                    "AjaxUrl": "<?php echo $ajaxurl; ?>",
                    "CurrentProduct": "<?php echo $currentProductId; ?>",
                }
            }
        }
</script>
```

and then in controller called another phtml file and load content from that phtml file using below type of code.

```
$result = $this->_resultJsonFactory->create();
$resultPage = $this->_resultPageFactory->create();
$currentProductId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('currentproduct');


$data = array('currentproductid'=>$currentProductId);

$block = $resultPage->getLayout()
        ->createBlock('Mymodule\Custom\Block\Index\View')
        ->setTemplate('Mymodule_Custom::customview.phtml')
        ->setData('data',$data)
        ->toHtml();

$result->setData(['output' => $block]);
return $result;
```

and in this customview.phtml I have loaded my dynamic content and then set to first phtml file using ajax response and it work fine with cache

```
<?php
$productData = $block->getData();
$productId = $productData['data']['currentproductid'];
$products = $block->getProducts($productId);
?>
<div>
  <div>YOUR HTML</div>
</div>
```